# Save data from dropdown at session and show in another page Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

Hello I have a problem using codeigniter.
Here I want to save the data selected through the dropdown into a session, then display the selected data to a page called step4. I have tried but when I display the data, it does not appear.

Here is the script:

Controller Step1.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Step1 extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('M_datasiswa');
  }

    public function step1()
    {
    $data['departemen'] = $this->M_datasiswa->get_departemen();
    $data['tahunajaran'] = $this->M_datasiswa->get_tahunajaran();
        $this->load->view('v_step1',$data);
  }

  function save_data(){
    $depart = $this->input->post('kode_departemen');
    $tahun = $this->input->post('kode_tahun');
    $asal = $this->input->post('kode_asal');

    $data = array(
      'departemen' => $depart,
      'proses' => $tahun,
      'asal' => $asal
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('step4');

    }



}
```

v_step1.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('Step1/save_data'); ?>" method="post">
      <table border="0" style="text-align:left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:97%; margin-top:50px;">
        <tr style="height:50px;">
          <td style="width:100px;"> </td>
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel" colspan="2"> &nbsp; Departemen </td>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 100px;"> </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <select required name="kode_departemen" class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="width:98%; margin-left: 7px; height:40px;">
                <option value="" disabled diselected>--PILIH UNIT--</option>
              <?php
                foreach ($departemen as $row) { echo "<option value='".$row->replid."'>".$row->departemen."</option>";}echo"</select>"?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height:50px;" >
          <td style="width:100px;"></td>
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel" colspan="2"> &nbsp; PPDB </td>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 100px;"> </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <select required name="kode_tahun" class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="width:98%; margin-left: 7px; height:40px;">
                <option value="" disabled diselected>--PILIH TAHUN AJARAN--</option>
              <?php
                foreach ($tahunajaran as $row) { echo "<option value='".$row->replid."'>".$row->proses."</option>";}echo"</select>"?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height:50px;">
          <td style="width:100px;"></td>
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel" colspan="2"> &nbsp; Asal Calon Siswa </td>
          <td colspan="1" style="width: 100px;"> </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <select required name="kode_asal" class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="width:98%; margin-left: 7px; height:40px;">
                <option value="" disabled diselected>--PILIH--</option>
              <option> UMUM </option>
              <option> KELUARGA YAYASAN </option>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height:50px;">
        <td colspan="8"><hr style="width: 98%"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px;">
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel" colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="buttonKembali" value="Batal Daftar" style="vertical-align:middle"> </td>
          <td colspan="4"> </td>
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="text-align:right; width:380px"><input type="submit" class="buttonSelanjutnya" value="Selanjutnya" style="vertical-align:middle;"> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

v_step4.php

```
<table border="1" style="text-align:left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:97%; margin-top:50px;">
        <tr style="height:50px;">
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel"> &nbsp; Nama Lengkap </td>
          <td> <input type="text" placeholder="Nama Lengkap" class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="width:98%; margin-left: 7px; height:40px;"/> </td>
          <td> <?php $this->session->userdata('departemen') ?></td>
          <td class="tulisanDalamTabel"> &nbsp; Nama Panggilan </td>
          <td> <input type="text" placeholder="Nama Panggilan" class="tulisanDalamTabel" style="width:97%; margin-left: 1px; height:40px;"/> </td>
        </tr>
```

Thanks, hope someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by does not appear? Are you getting an error message or page is just blank?

Comment: There are no errors, it's just that from the script above I want to display departemen data on the v_step4 page. Departemen data is taken from the dropdown in v_step1. When I wanted to display the departemen's data, it wasn't there.

Comment: Check what you have in your session variable. ``var_dump($_SESSION);``  And did you try starting the session before accessing the session data? ``session_start();``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to print using echo

```
<td> <?php $this->session->userdata('departemen') ?></td>
```

Do this instead

```
<td> <?php echo $this->session->userdata('departemen') ?></td>
```